# Java permutations of an array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array :

```
String wordArr[]=new String[3];

    [1 2 3]
```

I want to form arrays with all combinations of the above.

Say.,

123
132
213
231
321
312

Can anyone give me an idea on how to find the number of arrays needed and logic in java ?

Am figuring out on how to iterate through an array with all possible combinations. Say if i iterate for the first time with 123 then next time i should iterate through 132 and 213 and so on...

Comment: Shouldn't there be many more permutations for `1234`, e.g. `4132`? For `1234`, there should be 24 (4!) permutations, not just 8. If not, please explain the logic behind those "permutations". Also, have you tried anything, e.g. looking for related questions here?

Comment: yes you are right.Am figuring out on how to iterate through an array with all possible combinations. Say if i iterate for the first time with 123 then next time i should iterate through 132 and 213 and so on...

Comment: Where did 1324, 1342, 1423, 1432, 2314, 2341, 2413, 2431, 3124, 3142, 3214, 3241, 4123, 4132, 4213, and 4231 go?

Comment: "how to find the number of arrays needed"? Look up "factorial"

Comment: The proposed answer holds good for strings, but for an array the logic is different.

Comment: take the array and split it in parts

Comment: @ashwinsakthi Create a string of the arrays if you are lazy. Else, by seeing that code, you must be able to find out the logic for arrays too.

Comment: Why do it yourself?  I googled "java permutation" and got http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Permutations.java.html.  It almost works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is useful to apply [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) to the implementation of permutation. The basic idea is, for index `loc` which goes from 0 to array length, enumerate through all the possible pick for `arr[loc]`

I've implemented the following in Java, but it can be done in any language.

```
import java.util.*;

public class PermutationTest{

    private static void swap(char[] arr, int i, int j) {
        char tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
    }

    private static void permutations(char[] arr, int loc, int len, ArrayList<String> result) {
        if (loc == len) {
            result.add(new String(arr));
            return;
        }

        // Pick the element to put at arr[loc]
        permutations(arr, loc + 1, len, result);
        for (int i = loc + 1; i < len; i++) {
            // Swap the current arr[loc] to position i
            swap(arr, loc, i);
            permutations(arr, loc + 1, len, result);
            // Restore the status of arr to perform the next pick
            swap(arr, loc, i);
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> permutations(String str) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (str.length() == 0) { return result; }
        permutations(str.toCharArray(), 0, str.length(), result);
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        ArrayList<String> result = permutations("123");
        for (String str : result) {
            System.out.println(str);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted!

Answer (score 2):

This is pseudocode for generating permutations of any array **a**

```
Array permutations(a):
    if size(a) == 0 then return [];
    else:
        Array result;
        for i in range(size(a)):
            for t in permutations(a.remove(i)):
                result.push(Array(a[i]) + t)
        return result
```

Hope this makes sense, I'll try to make java code for this and upload it as soon as I can.